# Nuxt linter does not recognize injection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

Creating a fresh Nuxt project and installing firebase dependencies:

```
npm i firebase @nuxtjs/firebase
```

Following the library dependency [@nuxtjs/firebase](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/) in `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
modules: [
  // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
  // https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/
  '@nuxtjs/firebase',
],

firebase: {
  config: {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  },
  services: {
    analytics: true,
  },
},
```

If I log on a component:

```
console.log(this.$fire.analytics)
```

I see the expected object:
[image: $fire.analytics]

But in the Nuxt linter on terminal I see:

[image: $fire error]

Someone can help me to understand this errors? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I just find the problem! We need to add firebase types to `tsconfig.json`.

```
"types": [
  "@nuxt/types",
  "@nuxtjs/axios",
  "@types/node",
  "@nuxtjs/firebase"
]
```